# Magento 2 module dependencies

Tags: magento2-dev-beta, dependency

Is there a graph (or any other visual "thingy") to see how the core modules depend on each other in Magento 2?
(Yes, I tried Google, but he doesn't want to tell me.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.versioneye.com is a great tool to track Projects and its dependencies.

But as https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition is not part of http://packages.magento.com/ yet, we need to do a bit of magic to get it.

You need to create an own project and submit the [composer.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/master/composer.json) from github as reference. The result will be similar to this.
[image: versioneye visual dependencies]

Its so big, as it also shows all non magento dependencies and even php extensions itself or one of the dependencies depends on.

You may want also to look at the modules for itself, like the checkout module:
https://www.versioneye.com/php/magento:module-checkout/0.42.0-beta9/visual_dependencies
or the module-core: https://www.versioneye.com/php/magento:module-core/0.42.0-beta9/visual_dependencies

and here the dependencies of the framework itself: https://www.versioneye.com/php/magento:framework/0.42.0-beta9/visual_dependencies

Comment: it really  good :)

Answer (score 3):

https://alankent.wordpress.com/2013/10/19/magento-2-module-dependencies/ Is something I wrote a while back. Graph still ugly due to number of modules. But there are more optional modules.

Comment: Thanks Alan, but do you have anything more "readable". or is this an image for ants :)

Comment: I think it is intrinsically unreadable due to number of dependencies. I have tried various groupings, but none have helped enough. We really need to snip away at more circular dependencies first. I was just using graph viz - you can run directly and zoom in.